# How to assign query result to a global parameter in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have some problems getting the results from a postgre DB query into a parameter. 
i'm using node.js with pg, from which i want to get a value from the DB and assign it to a parameter and use it later in some other function.

My code looks like this:

```
var result2 = '';
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "pg://user:@localhost:5432/db";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM islocked');
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
result.addRow(row);
});
query.on("end", function (result) {
console.log("test: " + JSON.stringify(result.rows));
result2 = result.rows;
});
```

the problem is that result2 never gets updated with a new value. Why? How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?

I guess you could be trying to do a console.log() just at the end of your code and, if this is the case, you are checking result2 value **before** all query result data being collected and hence, before result2 value being altered in any manner.

Try this instead of a simple console.log():

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(result2);
}, 3000 // 3 secs. Increase to enought time to complete query execution if needed.
);
```

Answer (score -1):

i did it using files instead of connecting to a DB or an API.